# How can I unregister a handler set to jQuery.ajaxStart() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried doing `$.ajaxStart(function(){})`, but it does not replace it, but appended.

Comment: There is no such thing as `$.ajaxStart()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand, you want to remove the `ajaxStart` handler from the element.

If so, just use jQuery's `unbind()` since the handler is attached as an event.

```
$('selector').unbind('ajaxStart');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/unbind/
- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: That's exactly! I 've just figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Set global option to false

> $.ajaxSetup({ global: false });

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 2):

Worth to note that since jQuery 1.9, the `.ajaxStart()` must be attached to the `document`, hence you can't attach it to an element, or `unbind` from an element other than `document` for that matter:

> As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events, including those added with the .ajaxStart() method, must be attached to document.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).unbind('ajaxStart');
   $(document).unbind('ajaxStop');
 });
```