# How to prevent document.ajaxstart at only one place

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project,they use below jquery code, which calls ajaxLoader.gif for every ajax call

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
            $.blockUI({ css: { border: '0px none #aaa', backgroundColor:'transparent'}, message: '<img src="../common/images/ajaxLoader.gif" alt="Loading" />', overlayCSS:  { backgroundColor: '#08275d', opacity: 0.6 }});
        }
    ).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
});
```

I need to prevent this at only one place. **The user doesn't want this ajaxLoader.gif to appear at one place** where the ajax call is getting fired.

Do i need to add any code snippet before the ajax call and can i suppress this ajaxstart function there ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this one place, set option `global` to `false`, so `ajaxStart` won't be fired.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

> If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to
>   false, the .ajaxStart() method will not fire.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365456/how-can-i-unregister-a-handler-set-to-jquery-ajaxstart-function

Comment: I guess you will have problems if selector has multiple `ajaxstart` event. If you are going with `unbind` consider using a namespace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191485/how-to-call-ajaxstart-on-specific-ajax-calls/1212728#1212728